Improving proof: $f_n\longrightarrow f$ pointwise, $\{f_n\}$ uniformly Lipschitz, show $f_n\overset{}{\rightrightarrows} f$ not using Arzela-Ascoli
The problem is that, for $\{f_n\}$ real-valued compactly supported sequence of functions with $f_n\longrightarrow f$ pointwise, $\{f_n\}$ uniformly Lipschitz, say $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq M|x-y|$ for any $n$, show $f_n\overset{}{\rightrightarrows} f$ not using Arzela-Ascoli
My goal is to first show $f$ is continuous and using the below proposition:
Proposition
If $f_n\overset{p.w.}{\longrightarrow}f$, $f$ is continuous, then if for any $\{x_n\}$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{n}x_n=x$, the argument $\lim\limits_{n}f_n(x_n)=f(x)$ always holds, then $f_n\overset{}{\rightrightarrows}f$.
Proof of the proposition:
Assume not, then for some $\varepsilon_0>0$, for any $n$ there exists $x_n$ in the compact set such that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\geq \varepsilon_0$, $\{x_n\}$ have a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $\lim\limits_k x_{n_k}=x$, therefore $$\varepsilon_0>|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k})-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_{n_k})|\geq |f_{n_k}(x_{n_k})-f(x_{n_k})|\geq \varepsilon_0$$ for all $k>K$ for some $K$. The first term and second term are controlled by the assumption $\lim_n f_n(x_n)=f(x)$ and the continuity of $f$ respectively. Q.E.D.
I show the continuity of $f$ by the inequality:
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+M\frac{\varepsilon}{3M}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon$$
for $n>N=N(x,y)$ dependent to $x$ and $y$ by the pointwise convergence, the second term $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|$ is under control by the uniform Lipschitz.
Further I show $\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}f_n(x_n)=f(x)$ by:
$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\leq |f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}M+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$$
the first term $|f_n(x_n)-f_n(x)|$ controlled by uniform Lipshcitz, the second term controlled by the pointwise convergence of $f_n$.
Are there more natural and intuitive ways do this problem? By the insights of Arzela-Ascoli or not are both welcome. Thanks a lot.
